# VB script into SQL (VB making 2 inserts into one column)

Tags: sql, vba, sql-insert

I'm new to coding so pls take it easy on me.
I'm rewriting a Visual Basic to SQL.

The VB code inserts transformed data from a file into `tableY`.
I want my SQL code to load the data into `tableX`, transform it and load it into `tableY`.
I created `tableX` and inserted the untransformed data from the file. Now I want to transform it and insert it into `tableY` when I notice a problem.

Here is the VB code

```
IF some-if-statement THEN
    DTSDestination("max") = Mid(DTSSource("Col001"),985,5)
    another MID
    another MID
    another MID
    DTSDestination("max") = Mid(DTSSource("Col001"),983,5)
```

Here is my SQL version:

```
INSERT INTO tableY (max, aaa, bbb, ccc, max)
select
    substring(Col001,985,5),
    another substring,
    another substring,
    another substring,
    substring(Col001,983,5)
from tableX 
where some-where-statement
```

The problem is that I'm trying to insert 2 values `[substring(Col001,985,5)` and `substring(Col001,983,5)]` into 1 column.
Obviously SQL gives me an error:

> The column name 'max' is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same clause. Modify the clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If this statement updates or inserts columns into a view, column aliasing can conceal the duplication in your code.`

I am certain that the VB version works, even though it shouldn't - because it does the same thing.
Any ideas on how I can fix this? Inserting just one value won't work for me since I don't know which one is the correct one.

Comment: It seems you are just overwriting the Max field in the VB version. Do you want to store concatenated values in Max? Can you give an example of what the field values should look like?

Comment: Well between select case and if statements you should be able delegate what value needs o be part of the insert statement.

Comment: Could you provide the table structure for `tableY`? By your SQL, you have 2 columns named `max`.  Or as @Coolshaikh said, you want to store the concatenated value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the the VB script was overwriting the data. The second insert was the only one being actually inserted.